# If $M \simeq N$ in ${\tt stmod}(G)$ will $M \oplus \text{(proj)} \simeq N \oplus \text{(proj)}$ in ${\tt mod}(G)$?

Tags: representation-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and ${\tt stmod}(G)$ the stable module category for $G$, i.e., the category whose objects are $G$-modules and whose morphisms are $G$-module homomorphisms modulo those that factor through a projective module.

Is it true that two modules $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic in the stable module category if and only if there are projectives $P$ and $Q$ and an isomorphism $M \oplus P \simeq N \oplus Q$ of $G$-modules?

It's easy to show that if $M \oplus P \simeq N \oplus Q$ then $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic in ${\tt stmod}(G)$.  But the other direction eludes me.  If $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic in ${\tt stmod}(G)$ then there are maps $\phi\colon M \to N$ and $\psi\colon N \to M$ such that $\phi\psi - \operatorname{id}_N$ and $\psi\phi - \operatorname{id}_M$ factor through projectives $P$ and $Q$ respectively.  I tried defining a homomorphisms between $M \oplus P$ and $N \oplus Q$ using these factorization maps but I can't figure out how to do it so that they're inverse to each other.

Comment: Try this: Write $M=M'\oplus P_M$ and $N=N'\oplus P_N$ as $A$-module (your question is the same for any artin algebras $A$) where $P_M$ and $P_N$ are the maximal projective summand of $M$ and $N$ respectively, then now you can guess what $P$ and $Q$ should be, and write down the homomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In fact, there is a general theorem due to Heller, see [The loop space functor in homological algebra](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1960-0116045-4) Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 96 (1960), 382-394, Theorem 2.2:

> Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is an additive category in which idempotents split. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a class of objects in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $P \oplus Q$ is in $\mathcal{P}$ if and only if $P$ and $Q$ are in $\mathcal{P}$. Let $\langle \mathcal P \rangle$ be the ideal of morphisms of $\mathcal{A}$ factoring through an object of $\mathcal{P}$.
>
> Then two objects $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal{A}$ become isomorphic in the quotient category
>    $\mathcal{A}/\langle \mathcal{P}\rangle$ if and only if there are $P$
>    and $Q$ in $\mathcal{P}$ such that $A \oplus P$ is isomorphic to $B
>  \oplus Q$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

The proof is a slightly technical, but rather direct verification. Heller's argument is very clear, so I won't reproduce it.

See also [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13195/).

Comment: The hypotheses can be slightly weakened: $\mathcal{A}$ only needs kernels of retractions. If $\mathcal{P}$ happens to be the class of projectives and there are enough projectives one can drop this assumption as well.